# MySQL ORDER BY and LIMIT with variables in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE (
  id    CHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL,
  value CHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, value) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, value) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, value) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, value) VALUES (4, 1);
```

I want to retrieve values sorting and limiting, passing the sort field and direction as well as the limit value into a stored procedure.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(IN DATA JSON)

BEGIN

  DECLARE CASTED_SIZE INT; /* Declare variable to use it with @size */
  SET @user_id  = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.userId'));
  SET @size = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.size'));
  SET @sort  = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.sort'));
  SET CASTED_SIZE = IF(@size IS NULL, -1, @size); /* Asign size if not null */

  SELECT
    id,
    value
  FROM MY_TABLE
  ORDER BY /* Use a CASE to assign the correct sort. -id format wont work  */
    CASE WHEN @sort = "id"     THEN id    ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sort = "-id"    THEN id    ELSE NULL END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @sort = 'value'  THEN value ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sort = '-value' THEN value ELSE NULL END DESC
  LIMIT CASTED_SIZE
  ;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure('{"sort": "-value", "limit": 3}');
```

This works, but having to reassign the @size variable into a typed one, as well as the CASE statement for the @sort looks really hacky to me.

I can't see how this is not easier to do in MySQL. Am I missing something?

Does PostgreSQL implement this in a better way?

Comment: Why not simply do all the presentation stuff in a presentation layer?

Comment: You mean doing things like pagination in the presentation layer?